# after callback Appdelegate , all data is gone in current ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, appdelegate

I am using socket module for my app. First time , I 've used every UI for creating new socket connection that means every time user changes VC to another causes new socket connection.

So I've decided to move my socket delegates in to Appdelegate, and problem starts over there. I have a delegate which listens port and if there's any income event , it catches, de-serializes  JSon in to NSArray and sends back to current view controller which user sees.

The problem is , after that cycle, whole ViewController data just disappeared includes ( segue passed data from previous view controller ).

Here is my code : ( Updated )

in Appdelegate.m

```
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{

    NSArray *args = [packet.dataAsJSON objectForKey:@"args"];

    Mesajlar *MSG = [[Mesajlar alloc] init];

    [MSG didReceiveEventFromSocket:args];
}
```

In current ViewController  : (Mesajlar.m)

```
-(void) didReceiveEventFromSocket:(NSArray *)args
{    
    //NSLog(@"Instance called by Appdelegate");

    NSString *dataMode = [[args valueForKey:@"dataMode"] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *messageContent = [[args valueForKey:@"messageContent"] objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

After calling Mesajlar.m 's didReceiveEventFromSocket, Whole data and properties has just removed , I think that because , Once socket has received event, it just  come Appdelegate's instance without letting know Mesajlar.m, and it pushes Mesajlar.m's instance . Direction goes like that Mesajlar.m -> If any event call Appdelegate - > go to Mesajlar.M

How can keep connection alive and send events to other UI from Appdelegate without loosing current ViewController's properties ?

Best Regards.
Onder

Comment: what you mean by ViewController data?

Comment: show your code in the app delegate.

Comment: You're instantiating a new view controller with [[Mesajlar alloc] init], so of course it's not going to have any previous data. You need to get a reference to the one you already have. How you do that depends on your controller hierarchy.

Comment: Should i use NSNotificationCenter? or if it's yes, how it's going to be ? @rdelmar

Answer (score 0):

You may use notifications for this.
in your `AppDelegate` after receiving and parsing data, use this:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"data recieved" object:nil userInfo:@{@"data": dataObject}]`

and in every VC that you want to reload data or perform segue when data receives, add an observer for this notification.

Comment: should i use it in current ViewControlleR?  I updated my question , could you look the codes ?